# Need help to find a suitable regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame with one column of prices that contains strings of various forms such as `US$250.00`, `MYR35.50`, and `S$50`, and have been facing trouble in developing a suitable regex in order to split the non-numerical portion from the numerical portion. The end result I would like to have is to split this single column of prices into two new columns. One of the columns would hold the alphabetical part as a string and be named "Currency", while the other column would hold the numbers as "Price".

The only possible alphabetical parts I would encounter in the strings, prepended to the numerical parts, are just of the forms: `US$`, `BAHT`, `MYR`, `S$`. Sometimes there might be a whitespace between the alphabetical part and numerical part, sometimes there might not be. All the help that I need here is just figure out the right regex for this job.

Help please! Thank you so much!

Comment: There are many resources online to learn and test regular expressions. Do your part, have a try at it, and come back with any problem you cannot overcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to extend @Tristan's answer to pandas you can use the `extractall` method in the `str` accessor.

First create some data

```
s=pd.Series(['US$250.00', 'MYR35.50','&*', 'S$ 50', '50'])

0    US$250.00
1     MYR35.50
2           &*
3        S$ 50
4           50
```

Then use `extractall`. Notice that this method skips rows that do not have a match.

```
s.str.extractall('([A-Z$]+)\s*([\d.]+)')

           0       1
  match             
0 0      US$  250.00
1 0      MYR   35.50
3 0       S$      50
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked, but I used `extract` instead because I found the `match` multi index to get in the way when I wanted to insert the `0` and `1` column into the original DataFrame.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.match` on each cell with a regex like this:

```
import re
cell = 'US$50.00'
result = re.match(r'([A-Z$]+)\s*([\d.]+)', cell)
print(result.groups()[0], result.groups()[1])
```

The relevant different parts are captured in groups and can be accessed separately, while the optional whitespace is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Trick is to use ‘\$* *’ in your search pattern.

Since $ is a meta-character in RegEx, it needs to be escaped to be considered as literal $. So ‘\$*’ part tells RegRx that $ sign may appear zero or more times. Similarly ‘ *’ tells RegEx that space may appear zero or more times.
Hope this helps.

```
>>> import re
>>> string = 'Rs50 US$56 MYR83 S$102 Baht 105 Us$77'
>>> M = re.findall(r'[A-z]+\$*',string)
>>> M
['Rs', 'US$', 'MYR', 'S$', 'Baht', 'Us$']
>>> C = re.findall(r'[A-z]+\$* *([0-9]+)',string)
>>> C
['50', '56', '83', '102', '105', '77']
```

Answer (score 0):

With this regex

```
^([^0-9]+)([0-9]+\.?[0-9]*)$
```

Group 1 will be the currency part and Group 2 will be the numerical part:

https://regex101.com/delete/MjfCYY4H8g1uCfCywL0TFImZ